# How to edit variable in azure pipeline yaml file?

Tags: azure, variables, azure-pipelines

In the code below, the output of "echo ${{variables.myvariable}}" is always test.
I was expecting it to be test then uat.
How can I edit the variable value from the yaml file?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The format:  `${{variables.myvariable}}`  will be expanded at compile time.

When you use command to update the variable, it will be updated at runtime.

This is the root cause of the issue.

> I was expecting it to be test then uat. How can I edit the variable value from the yaml file?

To solve this issue, you need to modify the format to `$(myvariable)`  or `$[variables.myvariable]`

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)

Comment: thanks using $(myvariable) made it work